# What is wrong with this Smart Pointer Use?

Tags: c++, com, smart-pointers

I recently saw a PowerPoint on Smart Pointers and their pitfalls, which had this slide (with virtually no commentary or explanation:

*In context:* specifically the [_com_ptr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/417w8b3b.aspx), Smart Pointer for COM-interfaces that handles AddRef/Release, as created by a `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF` macro.*

---

**Wrong:**

```
IObjectPtr spObj;
for (int i(0); i<MAX; i++)
{
    //passed as actual , no release of previous ptr value
    spOtherObj->get_Obj(&spObj);
}
```

---

The next slide claims that it is okay if you put the `spObj` within the scope of the loop:

---

**Right:**

```
for (int i(0); i<MAX; i++)
{
    IObjectPtr spObj;
    //passed as actual , no release of previous ptr value
    spOtherObj->get_Obj(&spObj);
}
```

---

I've studied this, and still cannot figure out what they're talking about.
**What is the problem with the first one that is solved by the second one??**

---

I'm guessing that, in fuller context, the right/wrong code would look like:
*although I could be wrong in my assumptions*

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ICalendar, __uuidof(ICalendar))

void get_Calendar(ICalendarPtr* pCalendar)
{
    *pCalendar.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Calendar));          
}

void WrongMethod(void)
{
    ICalendarPtr spCalendar;
    for (int i(0); i<MAX; i++)
    {
        //passed as actual , no release of previous ptr value
        get_Calendar(&spCalendar);
    }
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't help that there's no context as to what `get_Obj` is doing.

Comment: pointers are always smart ;)

Comment: The context of this is all about the [_com_ptr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/417w8b3b.aspx) smart pointers to COM objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This most likely refers to [`ATL::CComPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266806%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and not `_com_ptr_t`.

The problem is that `CComPtr::operator&` returns the address of the wrapped pointer but doesn't release it, therefore leaking the objects if it is declared out of the loop, assuming that the wrapped interface is not NULL.

The implementation acknowledges this fact, this is copied straight from ATL headers, including comments:

```
//The assert on operator& usually indicates a bug.  If this is really
//what is needed, however, take the address of the p member explicitly.
T** operator&() throw()
{
    ATLASSERT(p==NULL);
    return &p;
}
```

`_com_ptr_t` fixes this problem, and is more convenient to use in general, so it should be preferred were applicable.

Comment: Very good answer.  And if you're right, no wonder I couldn't figure it out.  I keep looking at `_com_ptr_t`, which doesn't have this problem!

Comment: actually, I completely forgot about this problem with CComPtr until I saw your question :)

Comment: I can't recall if CComPtr still supports it or to, but it *used* to have a debug-mode for detecting invocation of `operator &` that would throw an assert if fired on a non-null instance. Don't know if it still has it or not.

Comment: Yes, it still has the check, I just looked it up in the source :)

Answer (score 6):

These are ATL::CComPtr smart pointers (which are marginally smart, btw).

The `operator &` for that object type returns the address of the raw interface pointer within. Therefore the first loop is literally no better than doing this:

```
IObject* pObj = NULL;
for (int i(0); i<MAX; i++)
{
    spOtherObj->get_Obj(&pObj);
}
```

With each iteration, the prior iteration's interface is never released. It is simply lost, leaked and the reference count on the underlying coclass will be artificially latched up.

By moving the smart pointer to the *inside* of the loop, you're now allowing the *destructor* of the smart-pointer object to clean up each interface acquired, firing `->Release()`,  before the next iteration. That code, expanded, is effectively this:

```
for (int i(0); i<MAX; i++)
{
    IObject* pObj = NULL;
    spOtherObj->get_Obj(&pObj);
    if (pObj) pObj->Release();
}
```